# sqlite3 python ATTACH DATABASE copy table .schema

Tags: python, database, sqlite

#### System

- Python 2.7
- SQLite3

#### Code

I want to restore a backup of a database by copying a table from the _bak.db to the being used .db.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join("data", "db", "Kanji-story.db"))
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS current")

c.execute("ATTACH DATABASE ? AS db2", (os.path.join('data', 'db', 'Kanji-story_bak.db'),))

# TODO Code for Creating table with the same structure
c.execute("INSERT INTO main.current SELECT * FROM db2.current")
```

#### Question

To execute the last statement I first have to create a table in Kanji-story.db with the same structure as Kanji-story_bak.db (see # TODO). How do I **create** a **TABLE** with the **same structure**? I know there is **.schema** command in SQLite3, but how do I effectively use that command to make a new table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inspired by the answer of @CL. , the full code is:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join("data", "db", "Kanji-story.db"))
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS current")

c.execute("ATTACH DATABASE ? AS db2", (os.path.join('data', 'db', 'Kanji-story_bak.db'),))

c.execute("SELECT sql FROM db2.sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='current'")
c.execute(c.fetchone()[0]) # Contains: CREATE TABLE current (framenum INTEGER, nextKanji INTEGER)
c.execute("INSERT INTO main.current SELECT * FROM db2.current")

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

SQLite has no mechanism to execute indirect commands.

To get the original table definition, you have run the same query used internally by `.schema`:

```sql
SELECT sql FROM db2.sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='current'
```

Answer (score 1):

My `sqlite3` version `3.18.0` has `create table main.current as select * from db2.current`

Comment: This is much simpler.

Comment: Note that this doesn't define a primary key, constraints or indexes for the new table. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html.